# Spring - No mapping found in DispatcherServlet, Request URIs include app name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, uri

I'm trying to build a Spring app from scratch and I made a simple app with the following directory structure and files.

[image: Eclipse folder structure]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>LearningSpring</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
       org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.learn.spring.app.web" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

**CentralController.java**

```
@Controller
public class CentralController {

    @RequestMapping("/profile.html")
    public ModelAndView showProfile(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        return new ModelAndView("profile");
    }
}
```

I don't understand what's going wrong in the above code, but I always get a 404 error. The tomcat log shows the following

```
15-Mar-2017 16:16:33.127 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /Users/SomeUser/Documents/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17/webapps/LearningSpring.war
15-Mar-2017 16:16:34.303 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
15-Mar-2017 16:16:34.501 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
15-Mar-2017 16:16:34.533 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Mar 15 16:16:34 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
15-Mar-2017 16:16:34.594 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
15-Mar-2017 16:16:35.238 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[/profile.html],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView com.learn.spring.app.web.CentralController.showProfile(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
15-Mar-2017 16:16:35.341 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Mar 15 16:16:34 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
15-Mar-2017 16:16:35.413 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Wed Mar 15 16:16:34 EDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
15-Mar-2017 16:16:35.517 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1016 ms
15-Mar-2017 16:16:35.527 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive /Users/SomeUser/Documents/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M17/webapps/LearningSpring.war has finished in 2,399 ms
15-Mar-2017 16:16:35.530 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [http-nio-8080]
15-Mar-2017 16:16:35.536 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler [ajp-nio-8009]
15-Mar-2017 16:16:35.536 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 2492 ms
^[15-Mar-2017 16:19:22.994 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LearningSpring] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
15-Mar-2017 16:19:27.755 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LearningSpring/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
15-Mar-2017 16:19:40.881 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-7] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/LearningSpring/WEB-INF/jsp/profile.jsp] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

One thing that I noticed is that all the request URIs have `/LearningSpring/` (The app name) as the prefix (which I guess shouldn't be there).

I'm not able to access the `profile.jsp` page via the URL `localhost:8080/LearningSpring/profile.html` and also the `index.html` isn't being displayed as the welcome page. It just throws a 404 when I access `localhost:8080/LearningSpring/`

I've read through a lot of answers and googled for hours but no luck. Please help by pointing what's wrong.

Thank you

Comment: solution1 : add this to your web.xml  <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern> and in your yourl localhost :8080/appName/profile.html solution 2: update requestMapping for your method      @RequestMapping("/profile") and in your yourl localhost :8080/appName/profile  best reagrards

Comment: @hichamabdedaime Tried it. didn't help

Comment: remove the folder metada in workspace and restart eclise  and try again

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things...

1. Change url-pattern of dispatcher servlet as "/";

`<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

2. Serve all static resources pass through the dispatcher servlet;

`<mvc:resources location="/**" mapping="/"></mvc:resources>`

Check this sample example - https://github.com/code-4-fun/spring-mvc-demo/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: Changing the url mapping to `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>` helped me solve the problem of accessing the `profile.jsp` page, but the 2nd thing did nothing and I still cant access my `index.html` page (as the welcome page)

Comment: @AdityaVikasDevarapalli  Are you sure _index.html_ file is under **webapp** folder and not **WEB-INF** folder?